# printf inserts random spaces in stdout

Tags: bash, printf, stdout

I have a `bash` script that uses `printf` to printout some colored STDOUT. I noticed that sometimes it insert spaces:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### define colors
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)

### 0. CHECK
# 1. docker
echo
printf "%40s\n" " 0.1. checking ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker${NORMAL} ..."
if [ ! "$(command -v docker)" ]; then
  printf "%40s\n" "   -> Please install ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker${NORMAL} first: ${BLUE}${UNDERLINE}https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac#dependencies${NORMAL}"
  exit 1
else
  printf "%40s\n" "   -> ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker${NORMAL} found"
fi
# 2. docker-compose
printf "%40s\n" " 0.2. checking ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker-compose${NORMAL} ..."
if [ ! "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]; then
  printf "%40s\n" "   -> Please install ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker-compose${NORMAL} first: ${BLUE}${UNDERLINE}https://github.com/cccnrc/diagnosticator-mac#dependencies${NORMAL}"
  exit 1
else
  printf "%40s\n" "   -> ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker-compose${NORMAL} found"
fi
echo
```

I got this output:
[image: printd stdout]

Why are there much more spaces before `-> docker found` than `-> docker-compose found` line when the `printf` command spaces are exactly the same?

Comment: Maybe you typed a `tab` character too, giving a harmonica effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color codes also take bytes, but are invisible. You have to take them into account.

```
printf "%*s\n" \
    $((40 + ${#BRIGHT} + ${#GREEN} + ${#NORMAL})) \
    "   -> ${BRIGHT}${GREEN}docker${NORMAL} found"
```

---

In Bash instead of:

> if [ ! "$(command -v docker)" ]

(prefer `[[` over `[` anyway, but) prefer:

```
if hash docker 2>/dev/null
```

`hash` will hash the command location, which will make any subsequent invocation faster, because Bash will not have to find the command again. And both `$(` and `[` spawn a subprocess, which is way slower than calling builtin `hash`.